# What is the time complexities of these two loops?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, big-o

For these two while loops I want to figure out the big O complexity. Not in detail just given these options: (O(log N), O(sqrt(N), O(N), O(N log N), O(N·N). This is an old exam question for which I cannot find the answer.

### Question 1

```
int i, j = N;
while (i < j) {
  i += 2 * j + 1;
  j++;
}
```

### Question 2

```
int i = 1, j = N;
while (i < j) {
  i += i;
  j--;
}
```

The answer to the first one is supposedly O(N·N) and the second one O(log(N)). It would be great if someone could give an explanation of the answers.

Comment: please write down *why* you think the first is O(n^2) and the second is O(log n).

Comment: In Q1, the value for `int i` is not defined. Typo?

Comment: Edit your first snippet. Its confusing.

Comment: first loop is O(1), second is O(logN)

Comment: note: for first loop, if `i` is negative (`i < -j`), then this loop will be O(N)

Comment: @FUZxxl in general case, first loop is O(N)

Comment: The first loop contains undefined behaviour, as `i` is not initialized.

Answer (score 1):

The first one, if i>=j, it's O(1).  if i and j are positive, it will go through the loop once, and end O(1).

If i is negative and j is not (>= 0), you will see that i grows slowly from i to 0, then when i is positive the loop stops.  In this case i grows at least by N/2.

If i and j are both very large negative numbers, i will become more negative until j reaches 0.  During this time i, will become much more negative at least by abs(j) each time, which is O(N * N).  By the time j reaches 0, it's already been O(N * N), so even though it's really quick once j==0, the answer should be O(N * N).

For this last case, i follows a sequence like (assume Z is positive number bigger than abs(N)):

-Z, -Z-2Z+1, -Z-2Z+1-2(Z-1)+1, -Z-2Z+1-2(Z-1)+1-2(Z-2)+1 .... (until j reaches 0).. then reaches some maximally large negative number of rough magnitude Z squared (say W).. then becomes W+2+1, W+2+1+4+1, W+2+1+4+1+6+1 ... until i>j.

So in worse case for all cases, first question is O(N*N).

The second one doubles i each time, so is O(log N).  Imagine if j is a really big number 1000000, and i = 1.  So (i, j) would be (2, 999999), (4, 999998), (8, 999997, (16...) (32, ) (64, ) (128, ) (256, ) (512, ) (1024, ) (2048, ) (4096, ) (8192, ) (16384, ) (32768, ) (65536, ) (131092, ) (262144, ) (524288, 999981), taking 19 steps.

Comment: Could you elaborate why you think it does not enter the loop in the first snippet?

Comment: @Olaf in case of positive i, first iteration will make i > j, (ie i + j*2+1 > j+1)

Comment: @Lashane: Since the initial value of `i` is unspecified (by error?), it is not possible to answer this right now. Until OP clarifies, it is just speculation.

Comment: @Olaf this question is not about C UB, but about bigO, so we can either assume `i=0/1` or `any random value`, for first case O(1) for second O(N)

Comment: @Lashane but big O is based on a worse case scenario so we would have to assume that it is O(N) not O(1)

Comment: @Lashane: Well, it is undefined not just in the C sense, but also in a mathematical sense. As you already confirmed, it is actually **not** O(1) as the answer states, but you have to seperate two cases, at least, antisipating OP forgot to give a constraint. As given, the answer is wrong.

Comment: On the mild assumption that the initial value for `i` does not depend on `N`, then the behaviour of the first is `O(1)`.

Comment: @Olaf N is also undefined in original question, we(I) just assume its positive and quite huge (at least unbounded)

Comment: @scerrecrow in this case I prefer to distinguish different cases and say O(1) for this range, O(N) for this and O(N*N) for that, in this particular case its actually important to understand different growth rate for different inputs

Comment: This answer is wrong; if the initial value of `i` does not depend on `N`, no matter how large or small or negative or positive that initial value is, the runtime is `O(1)`. See my answer for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

### Question 1

You didn't specify a value for `i`, so actually nothing can be said for the general case.

However, if we make the mild assumption that `i` does not depend on `N`, then the runtime is `O(1)`.

*Explanation*

For the large-`N` limit:

- `i` grows by `2N` each iteration.
- `j` is approximately constant.
- `i` needs to grow to become `N`.
- Therefore, it requires `O((N - i_0) / 2N) = O(1)` time.

This also directly shows that if `i_0` is a function `f(N)` of `N`, that the runtime is `O(f(N)/N)`.

---

### Question 2

The runtime is `O(log N)`.

*Expanation*

For the large-`N` limit:

- `i` doubles each iteration.
- `j` is approximately constant.
- `i` needs to grow to become `N`
- Therefore, it requires `O(log(N-i_0)) = O(log N)` time.

---

As a final note, this question assumes that `N` is positive, as per the usage of `N` in `O(log N)` in the question.

Answer (score -1):

In Question 1, since i and j are both initialized N. The while loop will not execute. Therefore, O(1).

The second question would just be O(logN) since i doubles every iteration.

Comment: 'i' is not initialized therefore it has the potential to execute. BIG O is based on a worse case scenario, meaning that the first loop will be O(N)

Comment: @scerrecrow It would not be `O(N)` necessarily, just imagine what happens if `i = -N!` (faculty function).